# Query a QGIS server WMTS using a RESTful URL as defined by the OGC

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-server, wmts, ogc, restful

## Context

I'd like to use the [WMTS](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wmts) from a [QGIS server](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/index.html) to serve a raster image as a base map in [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/).

## Description of the issue

I have set up a QGIS server to serve my raster image. Both [WMS](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wms) and WMTS work great.

I have a WMTS URL given in `Key=Value` format:

```
http://{baseurl}/?service=WMTS&VERSION=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities
```

which gives me the associated `xml` file with all the capabilities of my WMTS (provided by QGIS server). It works great. And I can see tiles by querying them with a `GetTile` request.

Now I would like to be able to use the [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) version of this URL in order to use it, e.g. as a base map to work with OSM for example.

So I tried:

```
http://{baseurl}/1.3.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml
```

But this gives me:

`Service unknown or unsupported`

This is how the WMTS is configured in my  `project.qgs`  file:

[image: WMTS options in the QGIS project file]

And this what the server tells while it is receiving the request:

```
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: ******************** New request ***************                                                   
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: Request URL: http://{baseurl}/1.3.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?                                    
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: Environment:                                                                                       
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: ------------------------------------------------                                                   
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: SERVER_NAME: {baseurl}                                                                       
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: REQUEST_URI: /1.3.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml                                                           
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: SCRIPT_NAME: /1.3.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml                                                           
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: REMOTE_ADDR: {baseip}                                                                       
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: SERVER_PORT: 80                                                                                    
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: QUERY_STRING:                                                                                      
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: REQUEST_METHOD: GET                                                                                
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8            
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83. 
0.4086.0 Safari/537.36                                                                      
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: QGIS_PROJECT_FILE: /etc/qgisserver/project.qgs
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: Trying URL path: /1.3.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml for /wfs3
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 WARNING [79]: Service  is not registered                                                                            
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 WARNING Server[79]: <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">                     
qgisserver_1  |  <ServiceException code="Service configuration error">Service unknown or unsupported</ServiceException>                      
qgisserver_1  | </ServiceExceptionReport>                                                                                                    
qgisserver_1  |                                                                                                                              
qgisserver_1  | 1626 - 10.192.90.216 - - [02/Jul/2020:10:27:41 +0000] "GET /1.3.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 432 "-" "Mozilla/5.0    
(Windows NT 10.0; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4086.0 Safari/537.36"
qgisserver_1  | 10:27:41 INFO Server[79]: Request finished in 1 ms
```

This RESTful implementation is defined on page 61 of the OGC document titled ["OpenGIS Web Map Tile Service Implementation Standard"](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=35326):

[image: OGC RESTful URL for WMTSCapabilities.xml]

## Question

Am I missing something / doing something wrong?
The panel dealing with WMTS in my QGIS project does not have much options and none of them is related to RESTful formatting of the URL.

Comment: Do you have a real live url for an example?. QGIS reads all of the above.

Comment: It's not published yet (internal research work). But the issue here is not getting QGIS reading a WMTS, but my web browser getting access to tiles served by QGIS server. It can fetch the tiles while requests URL are given in KVP mode, but it cannot in a RESTful format (for the exact same parameters), giving me the above message.

Comment: Just checking are you supplying the MAP parameter also when testing? In the docs it says it is required: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/services.html#getcapabilities

Comment: As the MAP is a unix path with folder names separated by slashes, I guess it can never work (I tried some ways, but none worked actually). And as stated by the [doc](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/services.html#map): "However, the QGIS_PROJECT_FILE environment variable may be used to define a default QGIS project. In this specific case, MAP is not longer a required parameter." + [more info here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/config.html#qgis-project-file)